# Using a single ADO Query to copy data from a text file into another ODBC source

Tags: c++, csv, odbc, oledb, ado

This may seem a odd question as I have a solution, I just dont understand why and that limits me.

I am copying data from various sources into SQL and am using a ADO connection in C++ Builder XE2.

When the data is from MSAccess or MSExcel the code is similar to the following:

//SetupADO..

```
ADOConn->ConnectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:/temp/testdb.mdb";
```

//Then open it..

```
ADOConn->Connected = true;
```

//Build SQL

```
UnicodeString sSQL = "SELECT * INTO  [ODBC;DSN=PostgreSQL30;DATABASE=admin_db;SERVER=192.168.1.10;PORT=5432;UID=user1;PWD=pass1;SSLmode=disable;ReadOnly=0;Protocol=7.4;].[table1] FROM [accesstb]";
```

//And finally I use the EXCEUTE() function of the ADO Connection

```
ADOConn->Execute(sSQL, iRA, TExecuteOptions() << TExecuteOption::eoExecuteNoRecords);
```

This works fine for Excel too but not for CSV files. I'm using the same driver must can only get it working by changing the syntax around.

//SetupADO..

```
ADOConn->ConnectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\\temp;Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=Yes;\";Persist Security Info=False";
```

//Then open it..

```
ADOConn->Connected = true;
```

//Build SQL with the IN keyword and start internal ODBC connection with 2 single quotes

```
UnicodeString sSQL = "SELECT * INTO [table1] IN '' [ODBC;DSN=PostgreSQL30;DATABASE=admin_db;SERVER=192.168.1.10;PORT=5432;UID=user1;PWD=pass1;SSLmode=disable;ReadOnly=0;Protocol=7.4;] FROM [test.csv]";
```

//And finally EXCEUTE() again

```
ADOConn->Execute(sSQL, iRA, TExecuteOptions() << TExecuteOption::eoExecuteNoRecords);
```

When using the same SQL as the Access query the error "Query input must contain at least one table or query" would be returned.
Intrestingly, one escaped quote, i.e. \' fails when used in place of the 2 single ones. I have also tried writing to another Access database in case the problem was with PG but I had the same results.

Can someone tell me why the IN keywork is required and what the single quotes do?

Answer (score 0):

`Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=Yes;\"` specifies text as the datasource, so the connection string is different. `IN ''` tells the database to map `table1` to the first column of the CSV file, since there is no relational model in CSV.

**References**

- [Importing CSV Data and saving it in database - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11435/Importing-CSV-Data-and-saving-it-in-database)